# Valgrind hangs. How to see what semaphore caused that?

Tags: c++, valgrind

At some point, valgrind hangs. CPU consumption is 0, nothing happens. The valgrind process is in state `usem` (FreeBSD). This happens after fixed number of time from starting in all modes I tried: "default mode", DRD and Helgrind.

How to break it and see the exact line of code where it is sitting now?
How to break it and see the semaphore it waiting for?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is to use gdb+vgdb to debug your application when running under valgrind. See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for more info.

If gdb+vgdb does not clarify, you might try to put more valgrind trace
(e.g. -v -v -v -d -d -d --trace-syscalls=yes --trace-signals=yes) and see
if that gives a clue.

And finally, you can use gdb on valgrind directly.